# Power shell Outlook interop assembly problem

Tags: powershell, outlook, office365, office-interop, office-automation

I'm trying to use PowerShell script to extract attachments from outlook item I have in a folder. The code is :`

```
# Specify the folder containing Outlook item files (.msg)
$sourceFolder = "C:\GRAINGER\GRAINGER\06-07-2023 Placements"

# Specify the parent folder where you want to save attachments
$saveFolder = "C:\GRAINGER\GRAINGER\Attachments\06-07-2023 Placements A"

# Load the Outlook COM Object
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
    using System;
    using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
"@

# Create an Outlook Application object
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application

# Get a list of .msg files in the source folder
$msgFiles = Get-ChildItem $sourceFolder -Filter *.msg

# Loop through each .msg file and extract attachments
foreach ($msgFile in $msgFiles) {
    $mailItem = $outlook.Session.OpenSharedItem($msgFile.FullName)

    # Create a folder with the same name as the Outlook item file
    $itemFolder = New-Item -Path "$saveFolder\$($msgFile.BaseName)" -ItemType Directory

    # Loop through each attachment in the email
    foreach ($attachment in $mailItem.Attachments) {
        $attachment.SaveAsFile("$itemFolder\$($attachment.FileName)")
    }

    # Close the mail item
    $mailItem.Close()
}

# Release Outlook objects
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($attachment) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($mailItem) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($outlook) | Out-Null
```

And I keep getting errors like :
The type or namespace name 'Office' does
not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Power...peCompilerError:AddTypeCompilerError) [Add-Type], Except
ion
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand

I have office 365 installed, and outlook also. But I'm stuck here ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the interop dll first

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
```

Or you can skip the whole `Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"` block and use late binding without relying on interop.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that an assembly reference is missing:

```
 The type or namespace name 'Office' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

So, you need to add assembly references before using the Outlook object model in the code. For example, here is how you may connect to the running Outlook instance or create a new Outlook `Application` instance if none is running:

```
Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
Add-Type -assembly "System.Runtime.Interopservices"
try
{
$outlook = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Outlook.Application')
    $outlookWasAlreadyRunning = $true
}
catch
{
    try
    {
        $Outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application
        $outlookWasAlreadyRunning = $false
    }
    catch
    {
        write-host "You must exit Outlook first."
        exit
    }
}
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
```